# Ubuntu Server 16.04 systemctl service with python script is running but not working

Tags: python, service, systemctl

i have read a lot of posts on this site on how to implement a python script as a service.

After fiddling around i am at the point that the service is started via systemctl (and running) but the script is doing nothing...

My config file in /etc/systemd/system/:

```
[Unit]
Description=tg Bot

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/tg_onduty/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/tg_onduty/on_duty.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Output:

```
user@server:~$ sudo service tg_onduty status
● tg_onduty.service - Telegram OnDuty Bot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tg_onduty.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-02-15 11:28:20 CET; 2min 17s ago
 Main PID: 1538 (python3)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 17.7M
      CPU: 351ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/tg_onduty.service
           └─1538 /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/tg_onduty/on_duty.py
```

I have read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645#339645 and understand that running the script via systemctl is different than running via CLI (via CLI /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/tg_onduty/on_duty.py is working).

My question is now:

How can i trace or see whats going wrong or why the script seems to do nothing? 
Via Journalctl i only see: Feb 15 11:56:17 server systemd[1]: Started tg Bot.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you script not running at all? try to put logs in your script to see if something inside the script doesn't work.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the small hint. i didnt have full path's in my script. As soon as i started the script from a different location it failed.

After adding full paths to my skript it worked through systemctl.

Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple action to the script. maybe echo something or create a dummy file. That is the easiest way to know if it's working